# Time intervals analysis in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, data-analysis

## Introduction

I have IoT devices that are constantly sending data to the server. The data consists of those fields:

- `state`;
- `state_valid`;
- `progress`;
- `timestamp`;

There is no guarantee that data will be received in correct time order, meaning that sometimes it might send data captured in the past, that removes the option to analyze and enrich data at the time of ingestion.

Received data is stored in `BigQuery` table. Each device has a separate table. The table structure looks like this:

- `state`: INTEGER, REQUIRED
- `state_valid`: BOOLEAN, NULLABLE
- `progress`: INTEGER, REQUIRED
- `timestamp`: TIMESTAMP, REQUIRED

## Requirements

After data collection, I need to analyze data adhering to those rules:

- Device is in received `state` value until different state is received;
- If record's `state_valid` is `false` - `state` value should be ignored and `0` should be used instead of it;
- If record's `state_valid` is `NULL`, last received `state_valid` value should be used;
- In analyzation phase, data should be viewed in one minute intervals;

  - For example there shouldn't be a final record that starts at 20:51:07. Start date should be 20:51:00.
- The state that was on for most of the time of one minute interval - should be used for the whole minute.

  - For example, if device had state `0` from 20:51:01 to 20:51:18 and state `2` for 20:51:18 to 20:52:12, 20:51:00 to 20:51:59 should be marked as state `2`.
- The resulting data should group all consecutive intervals with same `state` value and represent it as one record with `start` and `end` timestamps
- The grouped intervals of same `state` should have calculated progress difference (`max_progress` - `min_progress`)

## Example

Let's say I receive this data from device:

| state | state_valid | progress | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 2451 | 20:50:00 |
| 0 | 1 | 2451 | 20:50:20 |
| 2 | 1 | 2451 | 20:52:29 |
| 3 | 1 | 2451 | 20:53:51 |
| 3 | 1 | 2500 | 20:54:20 |
| 2 | 0 | 2500 | 20:55:09 |

Below I provide a visualization of that data on a timeline to better understand the next procedures:

[image: Data visualization]

So the received data should be processed in one minute intervals, assigning each minute the state that device was in for the better part of that minute. So the above data becomes:
[image: Data splitted into one minute intervals]

Then, consecutive intervals of same `state` value should be merged:
[image: Data grouped]

## Result

So, I need a query that would, adhering to the requirements described in `Requirements` section and given the data shown in the `Example` section provide me such result:

| group_id | state | progress | start_timestamp | end_timestamp | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 20:50:00 | 20:52:00 | 120s |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 20:52:00 | 20:54:00 | 120s |
| 2 | 3 | 49 | 20:54:00 | 20:55:00 | 60s |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 20:55:00 | 20:56:00 | 60s |

## Sample data

Consider those two data sets as sample data

### Sample data 1

Data:

```
WITH data as (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
    STRUCT(NULL AS state, 0 AS state_valid, 0 as progress, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as timestamp),
    (2, 1, 2451, TIMESTAMP('2022-07-01 20:50:00 UTC')),
    (0, 1, 2451, TIMESTAMP('2022-07-01 20:50:20 UTC')),
    (2, 1, 2451, TIMESTAMP('2022-07-01 20:52:29 UTC')),
    (3, 1, 2451, TIMESTAMP('2022-07-01 20:53:51 UTC')),
    (3, 1, 2500, TIMESTAMP('2022-07-01 20:54:20 UTC')),
    (2, 0, 2500, TIMESTAMP('2022-07-01 20:55:09 UTC')),
  ])
  WHERE NOT state IS NULL 
)
```

Expected outcome:

| group_id | state | progress | start_timestamp | end_timestamp | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 20:50:00 | 20:52:00 | 120s |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 20:52:00 | 20:54:00 | 120s |
| 2 | 3 | 49 | 20:54:00 | 20:55:00 | 60s |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 20:55:00 | `current_timestamp` | `current_timestamp` - 20:55:00 |

### Sample data 2

Data:

```
WITH data as (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
    STRUCT(NULL AS state, 0 AS state_valid, 0 as progress, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as timestamp),
    (2, 1, 2451, TIMESTAMP('2022-07-01 20:50:00 UTC')),
    (0, 1, 2451, TIMESTAMP('2022-07-01 20:50:20 UTC')),
    (2, 1, 2451, TIMESTAMP('2022-07-01 20:52:29 UTC')),
    (3, 1, 2451, TIMESTAMP('2022-07-01 20:53:51 UTC')),
    (3, 1, 2500, TIMESTAMP('2022-07-01 20:54:20 UTC')),
    (3, 1, 2580, TIMESTAMP('2022-07-01 20:55:09 UTC')),
    (3, 1, 2600, TIMESTAMP('2022-07-01 20:59:09 UTC')),
    (3, 1, 2700, TIMESTAMP('2022-07-01 21:20:09 UTC')),
    (2, 0, 2700, TIMESTAMP('2022-07-01 22:11:09 UTC'))
  ])
  WHERE NOT state IS NULL 
)
```

Expected outcome:

| group_id | state | progress | start_timestamp | end_timestamp | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 20:50:00 | 20:52:00 | 120s |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 20:52:00 | 20:54:00 | 120s |
| 2 | 3 | 249 | 20:54:00 | 22:11:00 | 4620s |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 22:11:00 | `current_timestamp` | `current_timestamp` - 22:11:00 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason I feel that updating existing answer will be confusing  - so see fixed solution here - there are two fixes in two lines at the very final select statement - hey are commented so you can easily locate them

```sql
with by_second as (
  select if(state_valid = 0, 0, state) state, progress, ts, timestamp_trunc(ts, minute) ts_minute
  from (
    select *, timestamp_sub(lead(timestamp) over(order by timestamp), interval 1 second) as next_timestamp
    from your_table  
  ), unnest(generate_timestamp_array(
    timestamp, ifnull(next_timestamp, timestamp_trunc(timestamp_add(timestamp, interval 60 second), minute)), interval 1 second
  )) ts
), by_minute as (
  select ts_minute, array_agg(struct(state, progress) order by weight desc limit 1)[offset(0)].*
  from (
    select state, progress, ts_minute, count(*) weight
    from by_second
    group by state, progress, ts_minute
  )
  group by ts_minute
  having sum(weight) > 59
)
select group_id, any_value(state) state, sum(progress) progress, 
  # here changed max(progress) to sum(progress)
  min(ts_minute) start_timestamp,
  timestamp_add(max(ts_minute), interval 1 minute) end_timestamp,
  60 * count(*) duration
from (
  select countif(new_group) over(order by ts_minute) group_id, state, progress, ts_minute
  from (
    select ts_minute, state, progress - lag(progress) over(order by ts_minute) as progress,
      -- ifnull((state, progress) != lag((state, progress)) over(order by ts_minute), true) new_group, 
      # fixed this line with below one
      ifnull((state) != lag(state) over(order by ts_minute), true) new_group,
    from by_minute
  )
)
group by group_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider below approach

```
with by_second as (
  select if(state_valid = 0, 0, state) state, progress, ts, timestamp_trunc(ts, minute) ts_minute
  from (
    select *, timestamp_sub(lead(timestamp) over(order by timestamp), interval 1 second) as next_timestamp
    from your_table  
  ), unnest(generate_timestamp_array(
    timestamp, ifnull(next_timestamp, timestamp_trunc(timestamp_add(timestamp, interval 60 second), minute)), interval 1 second
  )) ts
), by_minute as (
  select ts_minute, array_agg(struct(state, progress) order by weight desc limit 1)[offset(0)].*
  from (
    select state, progress, ts_minute, count(*) weight
    from by_second
    group by state, progress, ts_minute
  )
  group by ts_minute
  having sum(weight) > 59
)
select group_id, any_value(state) state, max(progress) progress,
  min(ts_minute) start_timestamp,
  timestamp_add(max(ts_minute), interval 1 minute) end_timestamp,
  60 * count(*) duration
from (
  select countif(new_group) over(order by ts_minute) group_id, state, progress, ts_minute
  from (
    select ts_minute, state, progress - lag(progress) over(order by ts_minute) as progress,
      ifnull((state, progress) != lag((state, progress)) over(order by ts_minute), true) new_group,
    from by_minute
  )
)
group by group_id
```

if applied to dummy data as in your question

[image]

output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is actually close to what I'm trying to achieve, but from the results I see that your query groups records by `state` and `progress` instead of only `state`. Meaning that if there are subsequent records with same state but different progress values, it will show them as separate records instead of grouping them to one group. Any idea how to solve that? Sorry for dumb questions but queries and databases are my weak link

Comment: For example if there are 3 subsequent records with `state = 3`, but progress of each of them is `2400`, `2450`, `2500`, I would expect there to be one group of `state = 3` with `progress` value as   `100` (`max(progress) - min(progress)`)

Comment: Btw, I love this question! Also love the way you presented and visualized it. obviously voted it first thing after saw it :o

Comment: I'm happy you appreciated the time spent for presenting the issue :) However, with my provided `Sample data #2` I still get multiple subsequent groups with same state (in this case `state = 3`). But maybe that's really something on my end. Will spend some time to find out what could be wrong. Thank you again!

Comment: ok. using your sample ##1,2 - I see the issue! Will look more into this - I think I know where this comes from :o)

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach:

```sql
WITH preprocessing AS (
  SELECT IF (LAST_VALUE(state_valid IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY ts) = 0, 0, state) AS state,
         LAST_VALUE(state_valid IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY ts) AS state_valid,
         progress, ts
    FROM sample
),
intervals_added AS (
  ( SELECT *, 0 src FROM preprocessing UNION ALL
    SELECT null, null, null, ts, 1
      FROM (SELECT MIN(ts) min_ts FROM sample), (SELECT MAX(ts) max_ts FROM sample),
           UNNEST (GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY(min_ts, max_ts + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)) ts
  ) EXCEPT DISTINCT
  SELECT null, null, null, ts, 1 FROM (SELECT ts FROM preprocessing)
),
analysis AS (
  SELECT *, SUM(grp) OVER (ORDER BY ts) AS group_id FROM (
    SELECT * EXCEPT(progress),
           TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, MINUTE) AS start_timestamp,
           progress - LAST_VALUE(progress IGNORE NULLS) OVER w AS progress,
           IF (LAST_VALUE(state IGNORE NULLS) OVER w <> state, 1, 0) AS grp,
           TIMESTAMP_DIFF(LEAD(ts) OVER (ORDER BY ts, src), ts, SECOND) AS diff,
      FROM intervals_added
    WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
  ) QUALIFY MAX(diff) OVER (PARTITION BY TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, MINUTE)) = diff
)
SELECT group_id, MIN(state) AS sate, SUM(progress) AS progress,
       MIN(start_timestamp) AS start_timestamp,
       MIN(start_timestamp) + INTERVAL COUNT(1) MINUTE AS end_timestamp,
       60 * COUNT(1) AS duration,
  FROM analysis GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1;
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I see there is issue with progress calculation. I've updated my question with sample data sets and with `Sample data #2` the `progress` for `group_id` #3 is `20` while it should be `249`

Comment: @hockeyman, fixed it.  **MIN(progress) --> SUM(progress)**.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I've considered both of the approaches (yours and the one that Mikhail provided). Both of the solutions works, however I can't mark both answers as correct ones, so I've given the correct answer to Mikhail, as that approach seemed more readable for me, who doesn't know anything about databases. However your approach is definitely working as well and could be used to solve my problem too.

Comment: @hockeyman, thanks for kind reply. This was the most well organized question I've seen and also the one made me chanllege to solve.  I've enjoyed it and reading Mikhail's code  is another pleasure.