# Analyse each identifier individually in single query on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

### Description

I have PostgreSQL table that looks like this:

| identifier | state | card_presence | progress | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| V000000000000123 | 0 | true | 1000 | 2022-12-01 12:45:02 |
| V000000000000123 | 2 | true | 1022 | 2022-12-01 12:45:03 |
| V000000000000123 | 3 | true | 1024 | 2022-12-01 12:48:03 |
| V000000000000124 | 2 | true | 974 | 2022-12-01 12:43:00 |
| V000000000000124 | 6 | true | 982 | 2022-12-01 12:55:00 |

I have to analyze this data quite frequently (at ~60s) intervals. First stage of analysis is a complex query which processes the data in multiple steps. At the moment the I execute the query for each `identifier` individually.

Basically what the query does is somewhat what is described in: [Time intervals analysis in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72887195/time-intervals-analysis-in-bigquery)

The query looks like:

```
with real_data as (
    SELECT 
        (CASE WHEN card_presence != false THEN state ELSE -1 END) as state,
        progress,
        lead(timestamp) over(order by timestamp) - interval '1 second' as next_timestamp,
        timestamp
    FROM telemetry_tacho
    WHERE driver_identifier = 'V100000165676000' AND state IS NOT NULL AND timestamp >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '2 weeks'
), sample_by_second as (
    SELECT
        state,
        progress,
        ts,
        date_trunc('minute', ts) ts_minute
    FROM 
        real_data,
        generate_series(
            timestamp, 
            coalesce(
                next_timestamp, 
                date_trunc('minute', timestamp + interval '60 seconds')
            ),
            interval '1 second'
        ) ts
), sample_by_second_with_weight as (
    SELECT 
        state, 
        MIN(progress) as min_progress,
        MAX(progress) as max_progress,
        ts_minute, 
        count(*) weight
    FROM sample_by_second
    GROUP BY state, ts_minute
), sample_by_minute as (
    SELECT 
        ts_minute,
        (array_agg(state ORDER BY weight DESC))[1] as state,
        MIN(min_progress) as min_progress,
        MAX(max_progress) as max_progress
    FROM sample_by_second_with_weight
    GROUP BY ts_minute
), add_previous_state as (
  SELECT
    ts_minute,
    state,
    min_progress,
    max_progress,
    lag(state) OVER (ORDER BY ts_minute) as prev_state
  FROM sample_by_minute
), add_group_indication as (
  SELECT 
    ts_minute, 
    state,
    min_progress,
    max_progress, 
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN state = 0 AND prev_state = -1 THEN 0
            WHEN state = -1 AND prev_state = 0 THEN 0
            WHEN state != prev_state THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END) over (order by ts_minute) as group_id
  FROM add_previous_state
), computed as (
  select 
    group_id, 
    min(ts_minute) as ts_minute_min,
    max(ts_minute) as ts_minute_max,
    min(state) as state, 
    MIN(min_progress) as min_progress,
    MAX(max_progress) as max_progress,
    min(ts_minute) as start_timestamp,
    max(ts_minute) + interval '1 minute' end_timestamp,
    60 * count(*) as duration
  from add_group_indication
  group by group_id
), include_surrounding_states as (
  select 
    *,
    lag(state) over(order by start_timestamp) prev_state,
    lead(state) over(order by start_timestamp) next_state
  from computed
), filter_out_invalid_states as (
  select 
    state,
    min_progress,
    max_progress,
    start_timestamp,
    end_timestamp,
    lag(state) over(order by start_timestamp) prev_state,
    lead(state) over(order by start_timestamp) next_state
  from include_surrounding_states
  where not (state = 2 AND prev_state = 3 AND next_state = 3 AND duration = 60)
), recalculate_group_id as (
  select
    SUM(CASE WHEN state != prev_state THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) over (order by start_timestamp) as group_id,
    state,
    min_progress,
    max_progress,
    COALESCE(start_timestamp, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '2 weeks') as start_timestamp, -- Add period start timestamp for the first entry
    COALESCE(end_timestamp, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as end_timestamp
  from filter_out_invalid_states
), final_data as (
  SELECT
    MAX(state) AS state, 
    MIN(min_progress) AS min_progress,
    MAX(max_progress) AS max_progress,
    MAX(max_progress) - MIN(min_progress) AS progress_diff,
    EXTRACT('epoch' FROM min(start_timestamp))::integer AS start_timestamp,
    EXTRACT('epoch' FROM max(end_timestamp))::integer AS end_timestamp,
    EXTRACT('epoch' FROM (max(end_timestamp) - min(start_timestamp))::interval)::integer AS duration
  FROM recalculate_group_id
  GROUP BY group_id
  ORDER BY start_timestamp ASC
)

select * from final_data;
```

### Sample data

**Input**

```
"identifier","card_presence","state","progress","timestamp"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,0,100000,"2022-12-01 00:00:00+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,0,100000,"2022-12-01 10:00:00+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,3,100000,"2022-12-01 10:05:00+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,0,100000,"2022-12-01 15:00:02+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,3,100000,"2022-12-01 15:45:00+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,0,100000,"2022-12-01 20:15:00+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,0,100000,"2022-12-01 20:15:00+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,3,100000,"2022-12-02 05:14:45+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,3,100000,"2022-12-02 05:15:00+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,3,100000,"2022-12-02 05:15:01+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,3,100000,"2022-12-02 06:10:00+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,3,100000,"2022-12-02 07:11:20+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,3,100000,"2022-12-02 07:11:28+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,3,100000,"2022-12-02 07:13:00+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,3,100000,"2022-12-02 08:01:06+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,0,100000,"2022-12-02 08:30:00+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,3,100000,"2022-12-02 08:30:10+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,0,100000,"2022-12-02 09:45:00+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,3,100000,"2022-12-02 10:30:00+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,0,100000,"2022-12-02 15:00:00+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,3,100000,"2022-12-02 15:45:00+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,0,100000,"2022-12-02 16:45:00+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,3,100000,"2022-12-03 01:45:00+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,3,100000,"2022-12-03 02:25:00+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,3,100000,"2022-12-03 05:18:00+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,0,100000,"2022-12-03 06:15:00+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,3,100000,"2022-12-03 07:00:00+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,0,100000,"2022-12-03 11:30:00+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,3,100000,"2022-12-03 12:15:00+00"
"0000000000000123",TRUE,0,100000,"2022-12-03 13:15:00+00"
```

**Output**

```
"state","min_progress","max_progress","progress_diff","start_timestamp","end_timestamp","duration"
0,100000,100000,0,1669852800,1669889100,36300
3,100000,100000,0,1669889100,1669906800,17700
0,100000,100000,0,1669906800,1669909500,2700
3,100000,100000,0,1669909500,1669925700,16200
0,100000,100000,0,1669925700,1669958100,32400
3,100000,100000,0,1669958100,1669974300,16200
0,100000,100000,0,1669974300,1669977000,2700
3,100000,100000,0,1669977000,1669993200,16200
0,100000,100000,0,1669993200,1669995900,2700
3,100000,100000,0,1669995900,1669999500,3600
0,100000,100000,0,1669999500,1670031900,32400
3,100000,100000,0,1670031900,1670048100,16200
0,100000,100000,0,1670048100,1670050800,2700
3,100000,100000,0,1670050800,1670067000,16200
0,100000,100000,0,1670067000,1670069700,2700
3,100000,100000,0,1670069700,1670073300,3600
0,100000,100000,0,1670073300,1670073420,120
```

### Question

The query usually takes some time to process for each device, and, I find that constantly querying for and analysing that data for each `identifier` separately is quite time consuming, so I thought, maybe it would be possible to pre-process that data for all devices periodically and store analysed results in separate table or `materialized view`.

Now the thing of running the query periodically and saving the results to a separate table or a `materialized view` isn't that hard, but is it possible to do that for all `identifier` values that exist on the table at once?

I believe that the query could be updated to do that, but I fail to grasp the concept on how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Without delving into your logic of analysis I may suggest this:

- extract the list of distinct `driver_identifier`-s or have it stored in a materialized view too;
- select from this list lateral join with your query.

Your query shall be changed a bit too, replace `driver_identifier = 'V100000165676000'` with `driver_identifier = dil.drid` to correlate it with the identifiers' list.

```sql
with driver_identifier_list(drid) as
(
 select distinct driver_identifier from telemetry_tacho
)
select l.* 
from driver_identifier_list as dil
cross join lateral
(
 -- your query (where driver_identifier = dil.drid) here
) as l;
```

Effectively this is a loop that runs your query for every `driver_identifier` value. However the view(s) are to be refreshed on every `telemetry_tacho` mutation which makes the effectiveness of the materialized view approach questionable.